# I cant debug my web service project in eclipse

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat7, jax-ws

I am doing one web service project in java. I am creating soap web service. I installed tomcat. I am starting server from bin folder startup.bat. and hit from postman. when i am doing this I cant debug the code in eclipse.
if i started server from eclipse then it is not accessed from postman. please tell me why this is happening and how will i do debug this project.

Comment: Share your code and error? Does the service works in normal mode( non-debug)? How are you adding breakpoints? how have you setup your eclipse with tomcat?

Comment: You can either start it from eclipse or connect to the server afterwards assuming there is a port configured for debugging.  I would advise the first if possible and launch in debug mode.

Comment: when i am starting server in debug mode from ecclipse . then i cant access it  from postman. it is  giving 404 not found error.

Comment: but i can access it. when i start server from bin folder.using  startup.bat. but i cant debug it when i start it from bin. and i gave  breakpoints also.

Comment: can we start server from bin folder in debug mode.

Comment: Check the first part of [this article](http://blog.trifork.com/2014/07/14/how-to-remotely-debug-application-running-on-tomcat-from-within-intellij-idea/) on how to launch in debug.  I'm guessing though that the ports setup in eclipse are different than the local configuration of tomcat.  Have you checked the configuration of tomcat in eclipse to see what ports are used?

Comment: yes i have seen ports are are default. 8080 in both configuration